# How can I hide a specific html section in IE8 only?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-8

I want to hide a specific section in my jsp page for IE8 only. I want it to be showed in other browsers like IE9, IE9+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox etc. Tried the following snippet:

```
    <!--[if IE8]>
       <li><a href="#/link">{{common}}</a></li>
    <![endif]-->
```

It hides the element in IE8, but also in other browsers too! I want it be hide only in IE8. How to acieve that?

Comment: Use javascript to delete the element if the browser is IE8

Comment: `<!--[if !IE 8]><!-->
<li><a href="#/link">{{common}}</a></li>
<!--<![endif]-->`
worked! thanks.

Comment: post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!--[if !IE 8]><!-->
<li><a href="#/link">{{common}}</a></li>
<!--<![endif]-->
```